# Can't enter 'Filters gallery' in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm kinda new to Photoshop and in a tutorial for Pin-up photography is was told to enter 'Filters gallery', but it is unavailable and I don't really know why.

I have a picture which I want to edit. Before that I made two layers by separating background from the rest of content and then I changed the layer with background to smart object and tried to access this Filter Gallery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you choose your image mode as 16Bits/Channel or 32 Bits/Channel, Filter Gallery option will become deactive.

Here is the image (you should the color bit in title RGB/32)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change the image mode, usually when you are working with RGB it allows you to access them (for use in electronic devises). If later you want to print your project change it back to CMYK and print from that file. I am not an expert either but this works for me.